# Lighter alternative to Computer-Aided Design software Fusion 360

Tags: 3d, graphic-design, cad

I wanted to use Fusion 360, a commercial software for 3D Computer-Aided Design modeling, created by Autodesk. to learn 3D printing on my computer, but [I have doubts](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14171/make-graphics-card-meet-fusion360-requirements) my 5 years old Inspiron 15 3000 series allows me to use it properly.

So I'm looking for your recommendations for either a cloud based or compatible alternative to it for such a machine.

Comment: You can try Onshape for free. It runs in a browser and works fine on my 5 year old MacBook Air.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.